# MY Android Studio Installed In E Drive So Where i can Find Android Sdk?

Tags: android, android-studio

MY Android Studio Installed In E Drive So Where i can Find Android Sdk?

I Watched Tons Of Video But Still I Can't Get The Right Way.

And After I Open My Old Project Gradle Start Downloading?

What Is The Error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are currently simply expecting us to solve the problem **for you**. **PLEASE** give it a try **on your own**, and if you have no clue please search online and learn the basics and then show us what you've achieved - and if you get stuck along the way, feel free to come back and ask for help.

Comment: `What Is The Error?` there is no error, it it is OK for Gradle to download everything it is missing. It is expected behavior

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Tools-> SDK Manager you can see the folder path to the SDK.
If you want to change it, you can copy the sdk folder somewhere else and then change it from this window.

Answer (score -2):

while insting android studio. when you download android sdk then there will downld gradle for project. you have to move that in c drive then user folder and and select admin and past it...